# Word substitution within tidy text format

Tags: r, text-mining, tidytext

Hi i'm working with a tidy_text format and i am trying to substitute the strings "emails" and "emailing" into "email".

```
set.seed(123)
terms <- c("emails are nice", "emailing is fun", "computer freaks", "broken modem")
df <- data.frame(sentence = sample(terms, 100, replace = TRUE))
df
str(df)
df$sentence <- as.character(df$sentence)
tidy_df <- df %>% 
unnest_tokens(word, sentence)

tidy_df %>% 
count(word, sort = TRUE) %>% 
filter( n > 20) %>% 
mutate(word = reorder(word, n)) %>% 
ggplot(aes(word, n)) +
geom_col() +
xlab(NULL) + 
coord_flip()
```

this works fine, but when i use:

```
 tidy_df <- gsub("emailing", "email", tidy_df)
```

to substitute words and run the bar chart again i get the following error message:

Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "character"

Does any one know how to easily substitute words within tidy text formats without changing structure/class of the tidy_text?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Removing the ends of words like that is called **stemming** and there are a couple of packages in R that will do that for you, if you'd like. One is the [hunspell package from rOpenSci](https://github.com/ropensci/hunspell), and another option is the SnowballC package which implements Porter algorithm stemming. You would implement that like so:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidytext)
library(SnowballC)

terms <- c("emails are nice", "emailing is fun", "computer freaks", "broken modem")

set.seed(123)
data_frame(txt = sample(terms, 100, replace = TRUE)) %>%
        unnest_tokens(word, txt) %>%
        mutate(word = wordStem(word))
#> # A tibble: 253 × 1
#>      word
#>     <chr>
#> 1   email
#> 2       i
#> 3     fun
#> 4  broken
#> 5   modem
#> 6   email
#> 7       i
#> 8     fun
#> 9  broken
#> 10  modem
#> # ... with 243 more rows
```

Notice that it is stemming *all* your text and that some of the words don't look like real words anymore; you may or may not care about that.

If you don't want to stem all your text using a stemmer like SnowballC or hunspell, you can use dplyr's `if_else` within `mutate()` to replace just specific words.

```r
set.seed(123)
data_frame(txt = sample(terms, 100, replace = TRUE)) %>%
        unnest_tokens(word, txt) %>%
        mutate(word = if_else(word %in% c("emailing", "emails"), "email", word))
#> # A tibble: 253 × 1
#>      word
#>     <chr>
#> 1   email
#> 2      is
#> 3     fun
#> 4  broken
#> 5   modem
#> 6   email
#> 7      is
#> 8     fun
#> 9  broken
#> 10  modem
#> # ... with 243 more rows
```

Or it might make more sense for you to use `str_replace` from the stringr package.

```r
library(stringr)
set.seed(123)
data_frame(txt = sample(terms, 100, replace = TRUE)) %>%
        unnest_tokens(word, txt) %>%
        mutate(word = str_replace(word, "email(s|ing)", "email"))
#> # A tibble: 253 × 1
#>      word
#>     <chr>
#> 1   email
#> 2      is
#> 3     fun
#> 4  broken
#> 5   modem
#> 6   email
#> 7      is
#> 8     fun
#> 9  broken
#> 10  modem
#> # ... with 243 more rows
```

Comment: Nice, the stringr package works well, only when i use str_replace i couldn't do some bits in one line (instead i did it in two steps):   mutate(word = str_replace(word, "coff(e|eee)", "coffee")). Is that because "e" and "eee" start with the same character?