# Removing all entires in a df beginning with numbers and combine tenses of words using R

Tags: r, text, tidyverse, word-cloud, tidytext

So I have a dataframe something like this:

```
word        count
employee    500       
jack        202       
employee's  199       
012hen      10
93          1
20          1
word        1
words       1
worded      1
```

So I have been trying to use gsub here but I am messing it up way too much.

Basically, I want to remove any entry in `word` that contains a number and I would like to combine word entries that have the same base.

So here, employee and employee's should be grouped together. Additionally so should word, words and worded.

Goal:

```
word        count
employee    699       
jack        202            
word          3
```

Comment: Have a look at [this tidytext answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43344108/word-substitution-within-tidy-text-format/43418097#43418097) about stemming.

Comment: Combining words with the same root is called "stemming", and it is a complex topic. Read [more about it here](https://smltar.com/stemming.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a partial answer, because I know how to remove all the entries with numbers. I am not sure on the second part about collapsing derivative words.

To remove numbers, you can indeed use regular expressions. I prefer to subset based the results of `grepl`.

```
df[!grepl("[0-9"], df$word),]
        word count
1   employee   500
2       jack   202
3 employee's   199
7       word     1
8      words     1
9     worded     1
```